# Are there Statistics Blocks for Warlock Patrons?

Tags: dnd-5e, religions-and-deities

I am playing a Warlock who plans on turning on his Fiendish patron, and I was wondering if there were specific stats I should consider. Or if I could do this at all (kill him/her).

Are there stats that I could look at to figure out how to do that?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52992/discussion-on-question-by-thepariah381-are-there-statistics-blocks-for-warlock-p).

Answer (score 12):

### What is in the Books

There are no stats for any devil above a pit fiend.  But there are stats for demons of type 6 balor and goristro, if these are archfiends or not is messy as demons don't have a defined pecking order like devils do.  Great Old Ones have no stats. Many Fey have stat blocks, but none that appear in 5e core books  would count as archfey. Gods have no stat block listing.

### Why aren't there stats

Really powerful beings can't be killed by heroes that aren't epic.  D&D rules max out just when you get to level 20 and become epic.  Epic campaigns or campaigns that become epic, therefore, are full of homebrew material because the rules don't go that high.

> When gods fight, the DM decides who wins. Such quarrels rarely work out well for mortals. #DnD

https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/775821324266590209 (still looking for another tweet about no god stats, will edit when I find it again)

### Your DM

What can or can't happen in a campaign isn't limited by the rules. 5e is very clear that the rules are guidelines not set in stone, and that the DM can allow or forbid just about anything to suit their game/story. So, the conversation that needs to happen is about god or archfey/archfiend/great old one death and about whether or not gods can be killed or their power stolen.

### Relvant D&D Lore

The writing in the D&D multiverse includes mortals seeking power of the gods. The most notable is Vecna. The necromancer Vecna was on the verge of becoming a god when the gods of the world intervened and killed him (or attempted anyway).  He didn't entirely die, and is constantly trying to rise again and finish what he started. Now, whether that is canon in your game or not is up to your DM, but it does show that godhood or near godhood is possible in the official multiverse -- and without slaying a god.

Comment: Archfey are constituted by those that hold court, like Oberron, Titannia and so on... a pixie from the MM will come no where close.

Comment: What makes an archfey doesn't exist in official 5e material, and Unseelie fey, to my knowledge, don't hold regular court like the Seelie fey do, but there are certianly unseelie archfey.  The unseelie and seelie devide exists in the lore of the D&D multiverse, but even that doesn't appear in official 5e core books.

Comment: Poor wording on my part, was an example that it is not the run of the mill MM entry was all. The Seelie and Unseelie thing has always made me cringe.

Answer (score 3):

Fiendish patrons run a wide gamut of different types of devils, as many different creatures from the Nine Hells can establish a pact to bestow the power of the Nine Hells upon a warlock. As far as I'm aware there isn't a canonical list of *which* devils can, but in the [*Brimstone Angels*](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/fiction/novels/brimstone-angels) series of D&D lorebooks (which span 4e & 5e), the lead character is a warlock who establishes a pact with a cambion, which is in the Monster Manual for 5e. Presumably, more powerful devils than them are also capable of it.

Do keep in mind that a clever fiend that suspects subterfuge is very unlikely to put themselves in a position where they can be killed (especially doing so in the Nine Hells, where they can be killed permanently)- they're likely to act indirectly through messages and proxies when they can.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the devils,

> Moreover, a contract with even the lowliest devil is enforced by Asmodeus's will. Any mortal creature that breaks such a contract instantly forfeits its soul, which is spirited away to the Nine Hells.

(MM, p.66 Dark Dealers and Soul Mongers paragraph), it will probably bring some more powerful entitites from the Asmodeus's ranks upon your character.

Comment: I feel like this answer needs more substance, more _meat_.

Comment: I might lack meat but definitely has a soul. Sorry for the necromancy (pun intended)

Answer (score 0):

The ArchLich is a patron with a stat block provided in the Dark Arts Player Companion.  It is a CR 30 creature so i would assume that other patrons would be around there as well. It has a spell save DC of 26 and a +18 to hit with spell attacks.  300ft truesight and a ton of resistances and immunities.

Comment: The [*Dark Arts Player's Companion*](https://www.reddit.com/r/UnearthedArcana/comments/4s0t12/dark_arts_players_companion_v10_now_doubled_in/) is a fan-created document.